# Batch write with deferent retentation policies in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I try to write batch data to influxdb but with deferent retention policies, but I could not find a way to do it without grouping the batch data with same retention then send each of the data in different batch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to write data with different retention policies in the same batch.